# Can't make tslint work with Sublime Text 3

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, lint, tslint

The problem is I can't make tslint work in my Sublime Text 3. Whenever I open any tsx file it shows "Linting..." in the tray for a while, but then always shows "tslint(ok)". Even though I know there are lots of errors in my code. I checked it by running tslint command in the terminal, where I get a big list of errors.

Here's my environment:
Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Sublime Text v3.1.1 Build 3176
Typescript v2.9.1 (installed globally)
TSLint v5.10.0 (installed globally)
NVM v0.33.8
Node.js v6.11.4 (runs through NVM)

I have installed all necessary packages in my Sublime Text, as SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-tslint.

Here's the content of settings of SublimeLinter:

```
{
"debug": true,
"linters": {
    "tslint": {
        "disable": false,
        "args": ["--project=${folder}/"]
    }
},
"paths": {
    "linux": [
        "/home/akbar/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin"
    ]
}
}
```

As you can see the debug setting is set to true, but there's no error in the console. I also read about tslint not working with NVM. But I fixed that by adding path to node executable in paths setting of SublimeLinter.
But I believe the problem is different here. TSLint seems like working, but it just doesn't catch any errors in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `env` option in the specific linter configuration, it should look like this:

```js
{
  "linters": {
      "tslint": {
          "disable": false,
          "env": "~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/bin",
          "args": ["--project=${folder}/"]
      }
  },
  "paths": {
      "linux": [
          "~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.6.0/bin"
      ]
  }
}
```

This should work on this environment:

- Sublime Text v3.2.1 Build 3207
- Typescript v3.5.3 (installed globally)
- TSLint v5.18.0 (installed
  globally)
- NVM v0.33.11
- Node.js v12.6.0 (runs through NVM)

See related issue [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/1218#issuecomment-388021005)